# How to measure the distance between camera and an object

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I'm working in a motion detection system to measure the distance from the camera to an object. Is there any function for this purpose? I know that to get the distance, you should know the time and speed. How can I achieve this using OpenCV3 and C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be achieved by having two cameras and applying stereo-triangulation technique inorder to calculate the depth frame.
Check the link below on how to calculate the depth from the frames of two cameras placed at different angles.
http://www.epixea.com/research/multi-view-coding-thesisse13.html

Update: if calculating the depth frame is not the main focus/goal of your project, you can use a kinect to get the depth frame.